# Difference between char** args and char* args

Tags: c, pointers

```
char** args = (char**)malloc(MAX_ARGS*sizeof(char*));
```

and

```
char* args = (char*)malloc(MAX_ARGS*sizeof(char*));
```

Please explain the difference between these two types of declaration. Why do we need 2 stars and why 1 star?

Comment: In both cases, the cast is unnecessary. The second is almost certainly incorrect.

Comment: Looks like a typeo on the second malloc where the size is char[MAX_ARGS*sizeof(char*)]. Depends what your intent though. Also I know this is possibly a learning exercise but for an array of fixed size (as is this example) using char* args[MAX_ARGS]; could be sufficient.

Comment: Most likely, the second `sizeof(char*)` should be `sizeof(char)`.

Comment: @Code-Guru: Except that you're not likely to want to allocate an array of `MAX_ARGS` characters. Most likely, the second is just incorrect.

Comment: @KeithThompson Granted, `MAX_ARGS` is a strange variable name when allocating the memory for a single c-string. The question about the difference between the code snippets only makes sense if the `*` is removed from the second one. Of course, the *real* question might be something different altogether.

Comment: Perhaps your actual question is "What do the asterisks mean?". My question is "Which book are you reading?".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both cases, the cast is unnecessary and can mask errors; I'll delete the casts in the following. (`malloc()` returns a `void*`, which can be implicitly converted to a pointer-to-whatever.)

```
char **args = malloc(MAX_ARGS*sizeof(char*));
```

This defined `args` as a pointer-to-pointer-to-char, and initializes it to point to a chunk of memory big enough to hold `MAX_ARGS` elements, each of which is a `char*`. Once you've done this, you'll want to assign values to those `char*` elements, likely making them point to strings.

```
char *args = malloc(MAX_ARGS*sizeof(char*));
```

This is *legal*, but almost certainly a logical error.  `args` is a pointer-to-char, which means it can point either to a single `char` object, or to the first element of an array of `char` elements. But you're allocating memory that can hold `MAX_ARGS` *pointers*.

A more likely thing to do is:

```
char *s = malloc(MAX_LEN);
```

which will cause `s` to point to a region of memory that can hold `MAX_LEN` `char` elements (a string of length up to `MAX_LEN - 1`). (Note that `sizeof (char) == 1` by definition.)

There's a useful trick to avoid type mismatches. A pointer of type `FOO*`, for any type `FOO`, needs to point to a chunk of memory big enough to old one or more elements of type `FOO`. If you write:

```
ptr = malloc(count * sizeof *ptr);
```

and `ptr` is a `FOO*`, then `sizeof *ptr` is the same as `sizeof (FOO)` -- but you won't have to update the line if you later change `ptr` to be a `pointer to`BAR`.

In your case, the pointed-to type is itself a pointer, so you can write:

```
char **args = malloc(MAX_ARGS * sizeof *args);
```

And when you call `malloc`, you should *always* check whether it succeeded, and take some action if it failed -- even if that action is to terminate the program with an error message:

```
if (args == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "malloc failed\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The two stars mean a pointer-to-a-pointer_type-to-data_type. So in the case of a char** this is saying create an array of char*[MAX_ARGS].

So for this case the following would be valid as **args[n]** is a **char***:

```
args[0] = (char*)strdup("aaa");
args[1] = (char*)strdup("bbbb");
args[2] = (char*)strdup("ccccc");
```

NOTE: you should remember to free each member of the array prior to freeing args otherwise the pointers are lost.

With a single star it is just a pointer-to-data and essentially you are writing char[MAX_ARGS*sizeof(char*)]

For this **args[n]** is a **char** type:

```
args[0] = 'a';
args[1] = 'b';
args[2] = 'c';
```

With this char-array you are creating a simple array of characters, also known as a c-style string.

Comment: can you please explain with an example

Answer (score 0):

2 stars are like matrix (or a two dimensional array). First malloc only gets memory for the first line (you have to iterave over its elements making the second malloc to reserve space for the other ones).

Comment: No, a two dimensional array is simply an array of arrays (everything is contiguous). `char**` is a pointer to a pointer. It can be used to implement a data structure that behaves like a 2D array, with more flexibility, at the cost of having to do your own memory allocation. Recommended reading: section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

Comment: I always though arrays and pointers were virtually the same thing - mostly when somebody tells me that a[3] and 3[a] were transformed into *(a + 3) and *(3 + a) during compilation. Surely I will read the faq, @KeithThompson.